# How do I include document fields within MongoDB $group aggregation?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aggregation-framework

Let's say my dataset is as follows **AFTER** completing a lot of aggregation magic on it:

```
{ "postid" : "5700edfe03fcdb000347bebf", "comms" : { "commenter" : "56f3f70d4de8c74a69d1d5e1", "id" : ObjectId("570175e6c002e46edb922ae6")}, "flag" : "M"}
{ "postid" : "5700edfe03fcdb000347bebf", "comms" : { "commenter" : "56f3f70d4de8c74a69d1d5e1", "id" : ObjectId("570175e6c002e46edb922ae5")}, "flag" : "M"}
{ "postid" : "5700edfb03fcdb000347bebe", "comms" : { "commenter" : "56f3f70d4de8c74a69d1d5e1", "id" : ObjectId("570176a3c002e46edb922ae7")}, "flag" : "F"}
{ "postid" : "5700edfb03fcdb000347bebe", "comms" : { "commenter" : "56f3f70d4de8c74a69d1d5e1", "id" : ObjectId("570176a3c002e46edb922ae6")}, "flag" : "M"}
{ "postid" : "5700edfb03fcdb000347bebe", "comms" : { "commenter" : "56f3f70d4de8c74a69d1d5e1", "id" : ObjectId("570176a3c002e46edb922ae5")}, "flag" : "G"}
```

Each line represents a post and then comment that is linked to the post sorted by time, with the latest comment in a post at the top and the oldest ones at the bottom. You can see this order by looking at the descending values of `comms.id`

Now I want to extract the data in an aggregation query so it looks like this. The data below represents the latest comment in all the posts returned:

```
{ "_id" : "5700edfb03fcdb000347bebe", "maxcom" : ObjectId("570176a3c002e46edb922ae7"), "flag" : "F"}
{ "_id" : "5700edfe03fcdb000347bebf", "maxcom" : ObjectId("570175e6c002e46edb922ae6"), "flag" : "M"}
```

The closest I have gotten to getting my result is running the query below:

```
group3={"$group": {
    "_id" : "$postid",
    "maxcom" : {
        "$max" : "$comms.id"
    }
}};
```

The code above returns this:

```
{ "_id" : "5700edfb03fcdb000347bebe", "maxcom" : ObjectId("570176a3c002e46edb922ae7") }
{ "_id" : "5700edfe03fcdb000347bebf", "maxcom" : ObjectId("570175e6c002e46edb922ae6") }
```

How do I return the output I require that shows the `"flag"` field as well?

Comment: Add `"flag": { "$last": "$flag" }` in the `$group` stage

Comment: I think you meant $first. The first aggregation function would return all the LATEST comments. The $last would return the last comments which means it would return the oldest comments. Thanks!